# Как из одного потока передать переменную в другой поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется два потока. Первый обрабатывает графический интерфейс, а другой должен получить значение переменной, вводимой пользователей в первом потоке. Я два дня искал информацию, но никакого толкового объяснения не нашёл.

```
public class s implements Runnable {
    public static void s(){
        System.out.println("тест");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        s();
    }  
}

class Testpotok {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new s());
        t1.start();
        System.out.println("тест1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте вашу реализацию потоков, чтобы понять как вам советовать. Способов довольно много.

Comment: @Komdosh я несколько не понял что нужно добавить. Просто только учусь поэтому немного не понял

Comment: Подразумевалось, что вам нужно добавить ваш пример кода. `имеется два потока` — они же не из воздуха появились, вы их как-то создали? Покажите, как.

Comment: подождите разберусь с тем как  здесь отправлять код

Comment: Графический интерфейс на какой библиотеке написан?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Swing  использовал генератор для создания интерфейса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing, как и многие другие gui-библиотеки, однопоточен. При создании окна создаётся [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), внутри которого будет работать цикл событий и обработчики событий. Вы не должны пытаться из главного потока или любого другого потока взаимодействовать с элементами графического интерфейса - это приведёт к сбою. Вы не должны внутри обработчиков событий запускать потоки - это приведёт к сбою. Если вам надо из другого потока изменить, например, текст метки, то придётся создать задание для EDT:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> someLabel.setText("Hello"));
```

Если вам нужно внутри обработчика нажатия на кнопку запустить на выполнение длительную задачу, придётся использовать [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Выполняется в отдельном потоке
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // Выполняется в EDT после завершения doInBackground
    }
};

worker.execute();
```