# Вывод HashMap в окно JFrame

Tags: java, javafx, коллекции, jframe, java-hashmap

Появилось небольшое курсовое задание. Я передаю данные с телефона на компьютер по Wi-Fi через сокеты. У меня 6 ролей в андроид-приложении и от каждого я получаю определенный ответ и записываю его в HashMap. Приложение нужно сделать на JFrame. Как вывести содержимое моей Map в окно JFrame? Основная проблема, что окно в JFrame должно постоянно обновляться, т.к. не все будут одновременно нажимать на кнопку. Если можно, то с примером кода, т.к. давно не работал с JFrame. Ответы вроде "загугли" или "да ты вообще ничего не знаешь, иди учи" не принимаются. Спасибо за понимание. Если нужен пример моего кода, то напишите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать? Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Если честно, то я не знаю, как реализовать вывод Map. Никаких ошибок. Там нужен элементарный вывод коллекции в окно

Comment: Это зависит от того, какой вывод в окне ожидается и что конкретно хранится в `Map`. Можно, например, преобразовать `Map` в строку и запихнуть её в `JTextArea`, а можно обойти в цикле все элементы Map и на каждой итерации создавать пару из `JLabel` для ключа и `JTextField` для значения. Тысячи их!™

Comment: Наверное, основная проблема в том, что у меня Map может быть пустой, и поэтому у меня выбросит NullPointerException, т.к. никто их пользователей может не нажать на кнопку

Comment: А Map нужно вывести в виде "СУДЬЯ 1: засчитано, СУДЬЯ 2: не засчитано, СУДЬЯ 3: засчитано"

Comment: Не имеет значения, каким способом, главное, чтобы вывод сработал

Answer (score 2):

Немного модифицированный пример из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

```
public class SimpleTableDemo extends JFrame {
    // Имена колонок
    private static final String[] columnNames = { "Судья", "Засчитано" };
    private final JTable table;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super("Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        table = new JTable(new Object[0][0], columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 1:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setData(Map<String, Boolean> map) {
        // Преобразовываем в двумерный массив для таблицы
        Object[][] data = map.entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .map(e -> new Object[] { e.getKey(), e.getValue() })
                             .toArray(Object[][]::new);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    }

    private static void start() {
        SimpleTableDemo demo = new SimpleTableDemo();

        // Исходные данные, приходящие из сети
        Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Kathy", false);
        map.put("John", true);
        map.put("Sue", false);
        map.put("Jane", true);
        map.put("Joe", false);

        demo.setData(map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SimpleTableDemo::start);
    }
}
```

Получится так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Может подскажете еще насчет одной темы? Как в Swing реализована многопоточность? Дело в том, что люди нажимают на кнопку не одновременно и нужно постоянное обновление окна для подгрузки данных. Хотел во втором потоке прописать постоянное обновление окна и после того, как все ответили, удалить все данные из HashMap.

Comment: Вам должен помочь [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814831/204271).

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли=)