# Метод вызванный из другого JFrame класса не работает (SWING)

Tags: java, многопоточность, jframe, jtextfield

Есть два класса, MainGUI и CardLayout с `JFrame`. В MainGUI создал `JTextField rfid`, задал параметр `setEnabled(false)` и создал метод setRfidEnabled (очевидно "включающий" обратно rfid). При вызове данного метода из класса CardLayout по нажатию кнопки, с `JTextField rfid` ничего не происходит, зато `System.out.print("LOL");` прекрасно работает. В чем проблема?
Заметил, что сначала класс MainGUI находится в `Thread[Thread-2,6,main]`, а после вызова CardLayout в `Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]`.

Класс CardLayout вызывается из MainGUI посредством класса ChangeLayout.

MainGUI:

```
public class MainGUI {
    volatile JTextField rfid = new JTextField("", 10);
    Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("MainGUI Thread: " + currentThread());
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main GUI Panel");
            JButton button = new JButton("CardLayoutSwitch");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
            final JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));
            frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pane.add(rfid);
            pane.add(button);
            rfid.setEnabled(false);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            Thread ru = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
                            LayoutChanger layout = new LayoutChanger();
                            layout.changeLayout(1);
                            printThread();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); ru.start();
        }
    });

    public void setRfidEnabled() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("LOL");
                rfid.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }).run();
    }
    public void printThread(){
        System.out.println("MainGUI Thread While CardLayout Launched " + currentThread());
    }

}
```

LayoutChanger class:

```
public class LayoutChanger {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
        gui.r.start();
    }

    public void changeLayout(int i){
        CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
        if (i == 1) {
            card.r.start();
        }
    }
}
```

CardLayout class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

public class CardLayout {
    public JButton manual = new JButton("UID MANUAL");
    Thread r = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Scan Panel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            final JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            manual.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
            frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pane.add(manual);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            manual.addActionListener(new scanRFID());
        }
    });
    class scanRFID implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
            System.out.println(currentThread());
            gui.setRfidEnabled();
            //frame.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из одного потока передать переменную в другой поток?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/814806/204271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все из-за бесполезных потоков, стоило переписать графический интерфейс "нормально", как все стало работать.
MainGUI:

```
public class MainGUI {
    JTextField rfid;
    JButton button;
    final JFrame frame;
    final JPanel pane;
    LayoutChanger layout = new LayoutChanger();
    public MainGUI() {
        rfid = new JTextField("", 10);
        button = new JButton("CardLayoutSwitch");
        frame = new JFrame("Main GUI Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        frame.add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(rfid);
        pane.add(button);
        rfid.setEnabled(false);
        button.setEnabled(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                layout.changeLayout(1);
            }
        });
    }
    public void setRfidEnabled() {
                System.out.println("LOL");
                rfid.setEnabled(true);
                button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

LayoutChanger class:

```
public class LayoutChanger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
    }

    public void changeLayout(int i){
        if (i == 1) {
            CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

CardLayout class:

```
public class CardLayout {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton manual;
    final JPanel pane;
    MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
  public CardLayout() {
            manual = new JButton("UID MANUAL");
            frame = new JFrame("Card Scan Panel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
            manual.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
            frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pane.add(manual);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            manual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                    gui.setRfidEnabled();
              }
          });
        }
}
```