# Как остановить\ запустить вывод элементов массива при помощи кнопки

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing, gui

Проблема: Я только начал знакомиться с GUI. Есть ui на swing, где реализовано несколько окон. В последнем окне есть поле(JLabel) в которое я передаю массив строк и с определенной задержкой все это печатаю(по очереди вывожу слова в это поле, удаляя предыдущее слово). Рядом с этой панелью хочу сделать кнопку JButton, при нажатии на которую вывод бы останавливался. При повторном нажатии, запускался бы. Не пойму сам алгоритм действия. Понимаю что скорее всего дело в многопоточности(с которой я пока что тоже на вы) Буду рад готовым решениям. Ниже приведу пример кода класса Printer, который и отвечает за вывод стрингов в лэйбл

```
package Core;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Поток для обновления JLabel'а
public class Printer extends Thread {
    private static final double minuteSize = 60000.0;

    private ArrayList<String> array;
    private JLabel textArray;
    private double speed;
    private volatile boolean isActive = true;
    //TODO доработать расчет
    private double smallWordsCoefficient = 1.1;
    private double longWordsCoefficient = 0.9;

    public Printer(ArrayList<String> s, JLabel textArray, long speed) {
        this.array = s;
        this.textArray = textArray;
        this.speed = minuteSize / speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            array.forEach(element -> {
                if (isActiving()) {
                    Loader.getMainWindow().getShowPanel().getStartMenuButton().addActionListener(e -> {
                        // Если нажали возврат в главное меню, то прерываем вывод
                        isActive = false;
                        textArray.setText(null);
                    });

                    // Выводим слово
                    textArray.setText("" + element + "");
                    // Перерисовываем панель
                    textArray.repaint();
                    try {
                        // Стопорим изображение
                        if (element.trim().length() > 4) {
                            Thread.sleep((long) (speed * longWordsCoefficient));
                        } else {
                            Thread.sleep((long) (speed * smallWordsCoefficient));
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                textArray.setText(null);
            });
            // В конце текста выводим сообщение
            textArray.setText("КОНЕЦ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textArray.setText(null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isActiving() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void stopPrinter() {
        isActive = false;
    }
}
```

вот место где этот код вызывается в окне

```
// Если пользователь ввел скорость чтения, то выводим слова на экран
speedText.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (speedText.getText().length() < 6) {
        speed = Long.parseLong(speedText.getText());
        printer = new Printer(getArray(), showElement, speed);
        // Делаем поток демоном
        printer.setDaemon(true);
        printer.start();
        // После ввода, делаем поле ввода недоступным
        speedText.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам или статьям!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопрос: [Как сделать обратный отсчет времени в java swing?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966362/204271)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из одного потока передать переменную в другой поток?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/814831/204271)